# Seeking better dictionary initialization

Tags: c#, python, perl, powershell, dictionary

I recently answered a question here with a PowerShell dictionary that used "ContainsKey" to decide whether to define a key value or add to it if necessary. I do that a lot - usually in C#, Python, R, or PowerShell these days, and I tire of it.

Is there a language - or even a library - that could do the following PowerShell code block in a single line?

```
  if ($sums.ContainsKey($skey))
  {
        $sums[$skey] += $sval 
  }
  else
  {
        $sums[$skey] = $sval 
  }
```

Comment: This is really too broad. In Python there is the [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict); `sums = defaultdict(int)`, then just use `sums[key] += val` and it'll auto-insert `0` for you if the key is missing.

Comment: Yeah it is broad, but should I have made 4 questions out of it :)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It's *sort* of too broad - but at the same time I think there are useful answers that can be written, IMO. I wonder if we can fix the question into something more obviously useful.

Comment: @JonSkeet: if this was focused on **one** language we can avoid the *and here is how you do it in language X!* list of answers this post is going to attract.

Comment: So four questions apparently... Anyway, I have two answers, that was probably worth the 2 drop in reputation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, that's definitely the problem - but the "What sort of approach can I use to avoid repeating this code" is a more tractable question.

Comment: @MikeWise: Well, maybe 3 - you should be able to use the same approach for both C# and PowerShell.

Comment: R could be solved by extending the hash library I suppose.

Comment: @JonSkeet: besides, for each of these languages, there are probably duplicates.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Possibly, possibly.

Comment: I was actually interested if any language out there actually addresses this issue directly. I suppose I need another forum for that.

Comment: @MikeWise:  you could even do this in Bash (v4 or later) with Associative Arrays.  An non-existing key does not give an error, but an empty string.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - turns out PowerShell has a better answer than C# (see mjlinor's answer below.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters - if this is such a terrible question, how come it is getting so much attention?

Comment: @MikeWise: weekend slump? Famous user answering because there are no better questions?

Comment: @MikeWise: and don't confuse popularity with *on topic*. As stated, this is too broad, which is why it is getting so many answers. There is no end to the number of ways you can answer this.

Comment: Hmm, you haven't answered my question about where I should have asked this then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) in .NET will allow you to do that, yes:

```
sums.AddOrUpdate(key, value, (k, v) => v + value);
```

You should be able to use that (with syntax changes, obviously) in PowerShell, too.

Alternatively, if you want to do this for plain `Dictionary` in .NET, you could add an extension method:

```
public static void AddOrUpdate<TKey, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
    TKey key,
    TValue addValue,
    Func<TKey, TValue, TValue> updateValueFactory)
{
    TValue existing;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out existing))
    {
        dictionary[key] = updateValueFactory(key, existing);
    }
    else
    {
        dictionary[key] = addValue;
    }
}
```

This is written to have the same effective signature as the `ConcurrentDictionary` method; if you only ever need a `Func<TValue, TValue>` for the update factory, you could change it accordingly.

I would imagine you could take the same approach in Python with a helper method - I don't know enough about Python to say whether you could do something like the extension method.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in one line in Powershell:

```
$sums[$skey] += $sval
```

If $skey doesn't exist as a key in $sums, it will be added, with a value of $sval.

If it does exist, the current value will be updated according to the rules for using the += operator on the type of the existing value.  If it's a number, it will do a mathematical addition, if it's a string it will concatenate, and if it's an array or collection it will add it as a new element.

Comment: I did not know this. And I am a little bit embarrassed that I didn't try it out. Thanks.

Comment: Is that using a normal .NET type under the covers, or a PowerShell-specific one?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It's a normal .NET type.  You can verify that with (@{}).psobject.TypeNames.  The behavior seems to be implemented in the operator.

Comment: @mjolinor: Right - interesting. So presumably that works on *any* `IDictionary<,>`? Really must learn PowerShell some time.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl (you did ask "a language"), you just add it:

```
my %sums;

$sums{$skey} += $sval;
```

If the key does not exist it will create it with a value of `undef`, which numerically equates to zero, and `$sval` is then added to it.  If the key does exist then the operation is as you would expect.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Because I used Perl a lot, but 15 years ago, I probably had this in the back of my head. Very cool.

Comment: @Mike Wise: If you used it 15 years ago then you might be interested in Googling "Modern Perl" - Perl has improved a lot.  Don't forget to `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

Comment: I changed the R tag to Perl, because I think that is more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Python (I am using Python 3 in these), there is [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) whose constructor takes a factory method, that is used to create default values for missing keys. `int()` returns 0, thus it is good for counting.

```
>>> import collections
>>> sums = collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> sums['a'] += 23
>>> sums['a'] += 12
>>> sums
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 35})
```

Or if you have an iterable of things, you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> sums = collections.Counter(['a', 'b']) 
>>> sums['b'] += 2
>>> sums.update(['c', 'd', 'e'])
>>> sums
Counter({'b': 3, 'c': 1, 'a': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1})
```

Say you have a function that asks for input:

```
>>> def input_skey():
...    return input("Give a next skey, empty line ends> ")
...
>>> sums = collections.Counter(iter(input_skey, ''))
Give a next skey, empty line ends> foo
Give a next skey, empty line ends> bar
Give a next skey, empty line ends> baz
Give a next skey, empty line ends> baz
Give a next skey, empty line ends> bar
Give a next skey, empty line ends> foo
Give a next skey, empty line ends> baz
Give a next skey, empty line ends> 42
Give a next skey, empty line ends> 
>>> sums
Counter({'baz': 3, 'bar': 2, 'foo': 2, '42': 1})
```

(the `iter(function, sentinel)` makes an iterator of repeated calls to `function` until the function returns a value that equals to `sentinel`).